# Always open application at rootViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

In my app I want the user to always see the `rootViewController`'s view when the app is opened even if the app has not been killed completely.

One alternative I have considered is calling `abort()` in `applicationWillResignActive:` however this doesn't seem like a nice solution.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend in your Info.plist to true.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you can also set "Application does not run in background" to "true".  This is found in the .plist.